# 'Spick and span' /British phrase for a flawless person?

Tags: expressions, british-english

I was wondering if there exists a British expression to denote a flawless/good/spotless person. I'm thinking of using it in a context similar to 'he's no saint', which if I'm not wrong, is American. I would like to be able to use it with the following sentence construction: "He's a far cry from **__**  himself."  Would it be correct to use 'spick and span' in this instance? Are there any other (more appropriate) alternatives?

Thanks very much.

Comment: American????????

Comment: The American spelling is 'spic and span'. But that refers to the state of cleanliness of a room and not a person in AmE.

Comment: I thought "Spic and Span" was just a brand name?

Answer (score 3):

*Spick and span* would be inappropriate to use in this instance as it usually refers to something being spotless; without a fleck of dust; usually a room or a home where everything is very clean, and almost shiny in appearance. I doubt many would use this expression to describe a person's character.

If you're looking for a British *type* of expression (but Americans will be familiar with these terms too) you could try these:

- 

> He's a far cry from being a [***good
>   sport***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/good+sport) himself.
>
> > ... a [***good egg***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+good+egg)
> >   himself.
> >   
> > (dated but understood)
> >
> > ... being a ***decent sort of chap***.
> >  [Longman's definition of *chap*](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/chap)
> >
> > He's a far cry from being ***perfect*** himself.
>
> To be "perfect" is generally understood to mean someone whose character is without flaw, I wouldn't classify the adjective as being British, although it fits in quite nicely with your phrase.

Answer (score 3):

One of the alleged origins of "spick and span" is that "spick" is a spike, or nail, which is shiny and clean when new; figuratively like *as bright as a new pin*. A "span" can be newly cut wood, so the general meaning of "spick and span" is "like new", and not really appropriate to apply to a person.

For a person, I would use "no angel" - *"he is no angel"* - or maybe "squeaky clean" - *"he is not squeaky clean himself"*.

Answer (score 1):

He's a far cry from an *angel* is common usage in the UK, but so is *saint*. *Mother Theresa* is often used as well, as in "not exactly Mother Theresa". With a different phrasing of the sentence, *impeccable* (without stain) would suit.

Answer (score -1):

My premise is their is no spotless/flawless person. yet it is possible for everyone to tend towards being a saint (or have some iota of it). hence to say "he is a far cry from his sainthood", would mean, "while he could have shown some gesture of being a truthful man, he is turning out to be a far cry from his sainthood".

Comment: Try to substantiate your answer with some good references, usage examples, etc. Support with links to the references. This answer could have earned up votes.

Comment: The OP is looking for flawless. Someone a 'far cry' from sainthood has -lots- of flaws. Can you explain what you mean?